# why it was infinite type ? (Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Tree a)

Tags: haskell, types, infinite

```
data Tree a = Branch a a | Leaf deriving (Show)

construct :: (Integral a) => [a] -> Tree a
construct [] = Leaf
construct (x:[]) = Leaf                -- _____error________
construct (l:r:xs) = if l>r then Branch l (construct $ r:xs) 
                            else Branch (construct $ l:xs) r
```

```
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Tree a
* In the second argument of `Branch', namely `(construct $ r : xs)'
  In the expression: Branch l (construct $ r : xs)
  In the expression:
    if l > r then
        Branch l (construct $ r : xs)
    else
        Branch (construct $ l : xs) r
* Relevant bindings include
    xs :: [a] (bound at C:\Stuff\code\New folder (2)\try.hs:69:16)
    r :: a (bound at C:\Stuff\code\New folder (2)\try.hs:69:14)
    l :: a (bound at C:\Stuff\code\New folder (2)\try.hs:69:12)
    construct :: [a] -> Tree a
```

why was it infinite type? This "infinite type" is input or output?

and also, If I change the `construct (x:[]) = Leaf` to `construct (x:[]) = x` then the error occurs in that `x`. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Let's start from the beginning:

```
data Tree a = Branch a a | Leaf deriving(Show)
```

This "tree", by definition, will contain exactly two `a` values (in a `Branch`) or none at all (`Leaf`). I'm not sure about why this is called a tree. It looks like this is not what you intended to do. Maybe you wanted

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a deriving(Show)
```

which is a tree with `a` values in the leaves. Or, alternatively,

```
data Tree a = Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf deriving(Show)
```

which is a tree with `a` values in the internal nodes.

Anyway, let's address your issue:

```
construct :: (Integral a) => [a] -> Tree a
construct (l:r:xs) = if l>r then Branch l (construct $ r:xs) else ...
```

Here, `l` has type `a`. Also, `construct $ r:xs` produces a value of type `Tree a`. Hence these have different types: `a` vs `Tree a`.

You then take this two values and pass them to `Branch` which, by definition, tales two values of the same type. The compiler tries to solve the type equality

```
 a ~ Tree a
```

but this immediately fails, since the only solution would be the non-existent infinite type

```
a = Tree (Tree (Tree ...))
```

Finally, to fix your code, you will need to modify your tree type so that it is actually a tree. After that, you will need to adapt your `construct` code to your new type.

---

> If I change the `construct (x:[]) = Leaf` to `construct (x:[]) = x` then the error occurs in that `x`. Why?

Because `x` has type `a`, yet the signature of `construct` promises a `Tree a`, hence requiring `a ~ Tree a` as in the previous case.